# HD68 -> HD68 SCSI Cable with angle

Tags: scsi

I trying to source an HD68 (Female) -> HE68 (Female) SCSI cable (2 meters) with one end of the cable with a 90 degree angle for an instrument we are using.  If does not matter if the 90 is a right of left as we are only concerned with the clearance from the back of the instrument to the container.

If there is an adapter that does this versus a cable that would work to, though looking around I have been unable to find any cable that match this requirement. Any information on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: There is a company that makes custom cables, http://www.techcable.com/HTML/SCSI-external.htm  But that is all that I can come up with.      Also, I am not sure if this question falls in site scope, it may end up being closed, as other questions along this line have been.

Comment: Had this as an answer but have no idea how more detail could be provided around a right-angle 68-pin SCSI cable apart from saying that it was, well, a right angle 68-pin SCSI cable: Google for Dell part number 5984D, which is a right angle 68-pin cable. There are a few places out there that have them in stock.  Hopefully this is acceptable as a comment.

Comment: @rnxrx I think that will probably work, I'll go ahead and order - I think the length will work.

Comment: @NZKshatriya - Thanks for the information, I sent a couple of emails to techcable but no response as of yet.

Comment: You are welcome, sorry to hear their customer service sounds to be lacking.  I am glad to see that you had better luck with the other suggestion made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this solution with the use of a couple of HD68 to IDC50 converters and an IDC50 cable. Not the best solution but it looks like the connector on the board was a bit too propriety (even though it was still a standard SCSI cable). In the end it worked and there does not appear to be any interference from using a short internal cable externally.

I was able to find the Dell cable (P/N: 5984D), though that did turn out to be male on both ends, it was worth a shot.

Hope this helps anybody that might run into this.

Comment: I am wondering who the board manufacturer was now.

Comment: It is a National Instruments board, the group using it are tied to them for various projects. Unfortunately we were unable to procure a cable from them for the environment this device was going in.

Comment: AH, I was half expecting a Dell/HP proprietary design board.